# Column formatting with JSON not working properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm new to sharepoint, so maybe I'm doing silly mistakes.

I made a list with few fields, one was a numeric field, where I added a JSON string to change the background-color by changing class of the div when the field contains a certain value, and it worked.

Today I changed the field to be a calculated one (it takes a date in another field and subtract now() in order to give me the remaining days to the event). The formula works but the JSON for formatting it, doesn't work anymore.

can you please help me?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField >15,'sp-field-severity--good', if(@currentField <=14 && @currentField >8,'sp-field-severity--warning', if(@currentField <=7,'sp-field-severity--blocked', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "line-height": "16px",
        "height": "14px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "",
        "class": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": "[$TTDL.displayValue]",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-LightGrayFont"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of your calculated column? What do you mean by it is not working correctly? Is it showing the wrong value or wrong background-color?

Comment: the formula is simple =([DL Requested]-NOW()) where DL Requested is a datetime column, the return type is a number. The value seems correct but the color gets messed up with no apparent logic

Comment: For testing, try adding `@currentField` to `txtContent` like > `"txtContent": "@currentField"` and see what values you are getting (add screenshot of it to your question if possible). Then you can add conditions accordingly.

Comment: thanks! i realized what was my mistake... it was related to the Today() date not working in the calculated field